# Laravel dusk not working .env.dusk.local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I have an application and I want to use Laravel Dusk.

I created a file named `.env.dusk.local` with a database for tests and a file named `.env` with my default database.

I ran the php artisan command and created a user by `/register`.

After I created a login test with the same email but with a different password, this would not be a problem because in `.env.dusk.local` it would be a different bank and would not have any users registered.

But when I run the php artisan dusk command it takes the information from the original `.env` and ends up erasing all records from my default database.

I would like to know how to load the information from my `.env.dusk.local` and use my test database.

.env default

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:K8otIkxJk0rFsZYSEq1hwBuaxQX3QI3Bb7ZmemJRIWg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_dusk
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

.env.dusk.local

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:K8otIkxJk0rFsZYSEq1hwBuaxQX3QI3Bb7ZmemJRIWg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_dusk_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Mu function for testLogin

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{


    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->create(['email' => 'lucas@example.com']);

        $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'secret')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home');
        });
    }
}
```

[Here is this project in github](https://github.com/thuram/laravel-dusk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .env file for test with Laravel Dusk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046749/how-to-create-env-file-for-test-with-laravel-dusk)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.env.dusk.local` try `.env.dusk`

Also instead of using your mysql database I would recommend using a temporary sqlite db since it gets created and destroyed during tests.

you will have to have a sqilte config in your database.php that points at an actual .sqlite file that you have in your installation

so copy the `sqlite` config in `database.php` and then paste it, name it `sqlite_dusk` maybe, then for the location of the db put it as `storage_path('dusk.sqlite')` or something like that. Then create a blank `dusk.sqlite` file in the root of your `storage` folder.

Then in your `.env.dusk` set:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_dusk
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: But https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#environment-handling says: "To force Dusk to use its own environment file when running tests, create a  `.env.dusk.{environment}` file in the root of your project.".