# Laravel dusk not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I created a application using laravel 5.4

Settings from my default .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:cMF768MPZ4ssHqG0InAUBnfvT4Ca0VaxsT6RwO3Geco=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_local
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

After duplicated my default .env and rename to .env.dusk:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:cMF768MPZ4ssHqG0InAUBnfvT4Ca0VaxsT6RwO3Geco=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

When I run the `php artisan serve` and then the `php artisan dusk` it renames my default .env file to .env.backup and .env.dusk to .env

But I keep running the migrations in my default database and not in my test database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel dusk not working .env.dusk.local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049060/laravel-dusk-not-working-env-dusk-local)

Comment: Your see https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/96

Answer (score 1):

I think your configuration might have been cached.  Try running `php artisan config:clear` before running `php artisan dusk`